# Ubuntu mixed boot

Tags: boot, gui, console

I have a problem during boot my Ubuntu starts with console interface, then switches to GUI.

In this video you can see how it happens:
http://youtu.be/-Ps26OCwsgM

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I don't see a problem, you first see a console but it goes to a normal interface?

Comment: Shouldn't it boot normally showing a logo or somthing like instead of _?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your grub commands to show you the splash/logo screen during boot up.  Use the editor that you are most comfortable with, vi, nano, etc.  Modify the /etc/default/grub file.  I use vi.

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

The modify the following line to match:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Save the file, with vi the code to save and exit is:

```
<ESC>:wq
```

Then update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your system.